# Jasper Reports Sever(Commercial) - REST API

Tags: jasperserver

We have downloaded Jasper Server Commercial Edition (Trial Version) and we are able to install, Login and publish reports too from Jasper Server UI.

But, We are not able to log in to `REST` Client which is provided by Jasper.

Does Trail Edition supports `REST` Services enabled? Why because We are not able to login with `REST` Client.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the trial of the Enterprise Edition supports everything that is supported on a fully licensed server, including the REST API.

Can you provide the code you have tested and the output you see when running that code, particularly any errors?

Comment: Yes, All features are avilable in Trail version.

Comment: What id `Trail Edition`?

Comment: What is id here ? I don't understand.